# How do you specify the http referrer in golang as client?

Tags: http, go, referrer

Using the standard http.Client, how do you build a web request that specifies a referrer in the http request header?

Below you can see it is possible to set headers, but how do you specify the referer? Is it just by setting a Referer header?

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
req.Header.Set("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml")
req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1)")

response, err1 := client.Get(url)
if err1 != nil {
    return "", err1
}
```

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.36

Comment: Yes, Referer is a header. Have you tried setting it?

Comment: @JimB If I knew how to set it I would have not needed to ask this question. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as you can see from the sources from Go itself, in [`src/net/http/client.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/client.go#L563-L567)

```
// Add the Referer header from the most recent
// request URL to the new one, if it's not https->http:
if ref := refererForURL(reqs[len(reqs)-1].URL, req.URL); ref != "" {
    req.Header.Set("Referer", ref)
}
```

Check your scheme though, [as in the same sources](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/client.go#L142-L148):

```
// refererForURL returns a referer without any authentication info or
// an empty string if lastReq scheme is https and newReq scheme is http.
func refererForURL(lastReq, newReq *url.URL) string {
    // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.5.2
    //   "Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a
    //    (non-secure) HTTP request if the referring page was
    //    transferred with a secure protocol."
    if lastReq.Scheme == "https" && newReq.Scheme == "http" {
        return ""
}
```